# Recursive Pattern match in .tpattributes file [TFS 2010]

Tags: tfs, executable

I'm trying to use a .tpattributes file to retain Execute permissions on all files under a directory in my project. However, it appears the attribute is only applied to the top level folder, and I can't find a way to make it recursive.

Attempt 1:

```
#Trying to prevent TFS from screwing up files like it loves to do
.**\/*:x
```

Attempt 2:

```
#Trying to prevent TFS from screwing up files like it loves to do
.*/*:x
```

The documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413272(v=vs.100).aspx) isn't very helpful, and I haven't been able to find any other documentation for .tpattributes files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.tpattributes` are *not* recursive.  (In fact, they cannot be, since you can have advanced workspace mappings.)  You will need a `.tpattributes` in each folder.

Executable permissions are handled automatically, without the need for `.tpattributes` in TFS 2013 and newer.

Comment: This is unfortunate :( but what I was expecting. TFS has been a real bummer to work with. Thanks for the info.

Comment: TFS 2010 is tuned for supporting very large repositories over usability.  TFS 2012 introduces edit/merge/commit style workflows (similar to Subversion).  TFS 2013 introduces distributed version control (using Git).  These workflows may be more enjoyable for you.

Comment: is `*:x`  a valid pattern for all files in the directory? I'm now having no luck getting .tpattributes to work at all. Also, is it correct to run a `tf get -all` once I update the .tpattributes file to test if the .tpattirbutes file is working correctly, or do I have to setup a whole new workspace if the file is pulled down with wrong permissions the first time?

Comment: @Barryrowe You probably want `.*:x` to match all files.  You should be able to do `tf get -force` to have it re-apply the `.tpattributes`.

Comment: Thanks. the `-force` flag seems like what I was missing. Now I just have to find every directory with an executable :S  (ps. this is a cordova project, so this has to do with the cordova build scripts)