# Converting TFS source code to GIT. Is .tpattributes syntax equal to .gitattributes syntax?

Tags: git, tfs, gitattributes

I am converting my source code from TFS to Git and I want to convert any `.tpattributes` files into `.gitattributes` files.

It appears the pattern syntax is the same for both files, so I am wondering if it as simple as renaming my `.tpattributes` files to `.gitattributes` files?
Or will more need to be done to ensure the syntax is compatible with Git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *start* by renamming the `.tpattributes` files, but, do check (with a git status before and after) that it does not ignore too much.

As mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25557977/6309)

> `.tpattributes` are not recursive. (In fact, they cannot be, since you can have advanced workspace mappings.)
>   You will need a `.tpattributes` in each folder.

However, a `.gitignore` applies to the current folder, and all folders below.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I would be renaming all .tpattributes files wherever they are located so I just want to ensure the syntax used in .tpattributes will be understood by Git when I rename to .gitattributes.  I don't want anything to be excluded.

Comment: @DCantacesso Exactly: do check the syntax does follow a [shell glob syntax, fnmatch-style](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html), and you will get the same result with the renamed `.gitignore` files (but, again, those rules will be applied recursively)